# Multiple dist targets

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake

I'm facing the need to build more than one distribution tarball. Currently I have dist target which builds distribution tar ball using `./autogen && ./configure && make dist` at the project directory. I'd like to be able to build a second distribution package which includes only some parts of the "regular" distribution package. How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: That's not how "distribution" is supposed to work. You package everything, the user chooses if he wants only a subset built. Automake won't help you distribute a gutted version of your package; it's not a matter of just leaving files out, your configure.ac needs to know the exact list of Makefiles, and SUBDIRs need to be set correctly.